# Should I use 10.04 or 12.04?

Tags: unity, 10.04, 12.04, lts

1. I heard a lot of things about power regression in Linux Kernel. After releasing 12.04 LTS, most of the issues have been cleared but not all.

   There is an article on Ubuntu which says "Its a mixed one".. For some people, its best release in terms of power management and for some, its the same.

   http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_pangolin_power&num=1
2. Switching hybrid graphics; Its still not as good as in windows.
3. The new unity desktop.

etc..

Considering all these issues, which should I prefer,

10.04 LTS or 12.04 LTS?

**Updated**

My hardware:

Lenovo G570; 
Intel 2nd Gen i5 ; 4GB DDR3 RAM;
Intel in-build graphics + AMD Radeon HD 6370M - 1GB

*I am very much looking for an Ubuntu OS which is really as good as windows. Especially in switching hybrid graphics, installing binaries etc..*

**Update 2**
Powertop results using 12.04 Live CD.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more information about your hardware and your needs?

Comment: I suppose it depends on your hardware and if you are affected by any of these kernel (power) issues. You should take 12.04 for a test driver (live CD) and file bug reports if you have problems.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen  How am I supposed to know all these using a "live CD". Installing drivers using live disk etc is big job. is there a way that you can tell me

Comment: The "drivers" are either built into the kernel or loaded as modules. There is no need to install anything. If you can not describe a problem you are having, we can not really solve it.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen well, lets say I am using Live CD. Now, how to find out how much power my laptop is consuming and how should I compare it with my Win7 consumption.

Comment: Benchmarks are probably best - http://www.phoronix-test-suite.com/

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have used powertop on Live CD and found that the battery discharging rate is around 16 - 18 W, when I didn't open any applications. The screen brightness was at 2 / 3 points. So, is that supposed to working fine??

Comment: You will need to compare to other kernels (previous versions of Ubuntu), windows, benchmarks ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not install 10.04 LTS on your system for a number of reasons.  Most importantly, I don't think 10.04 will *install* on your machine - your SandyBridge Core i5 was released significantly after April 2010, so Ubuntu 10.04 does not have drivers for it.

Additionally, your hybrid graphics system will be entirely unsupported, rather than merely requiring a bit of extra work - see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124671/how-to-fix-high-power-consumption-on-a-hybrid-) for how to get Ubuntu to turn off your discrete card (which will obviously reduce power consumption *significantly*).

If I switch all the relevant power saving knobs, *my* hybrid Core i5 laptop idles at around 9W with 12.04, which isn't terrible.

Comment: What exactly is the ideal power consumption in ubuntu when its in idle state? you said its 9W in your laptop. So, how much exactly it could be in windows 7

Comment: I haven't measured it in Windows 7; I haven't *installed* Windows 7 on it.  It *does* manage about 7 hours non-intensive real-world use, or 10 hours long-haul plane use on the standard battery, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are way too many enhancements, fixes and improvements compared to 10.04 to just take into consideration the power consumption. Nevertheless, if this is a big problem, the latest updates to 12.04 have fixed many problems and they keep on coming.

So my recommendation is to move to 12.04 and update it to the latest available fixes you see on the Update Manager. Additionally you happen to have new hardware that is better suited for 12.04 than 10.04. 12.04 can provide better performance in general with that hardware. Not only that but most of the PPAs and up to date work that many developers are doing are for 12.04. For example bumblebee for your dual-video hybrid.

I could make this answer very long if I start talking about what 12.04 brings to the table. For what is worth, in my PC which is a Core i7 Ubuntu loads and responds better than Windows 7 on the same machine. Boots faster and it feels just fast overall.

Answer (score 0):

10.04 will not have any more security fixes issued as its desktop version's support was for 3 years. So you'd better start using 12.04 and slowly fix the issues with each security and performance fixes.

Comment: I edited it to 10.04